# MVC Html.ValueFor not setting value in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sorry for what could potentially be a stupid question but I've been going round in circles all afternoon.  I have a form in MVC which posts back to an action on the controller.  The view that the form is on takes a model and this sets some of the fields.  I need these fields to be passed back into the model when the action is called on the controller.
e.g.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValueFor(m=>m.test);
  ...
  //submit button
}
```

Currently the test property is null when it reaches the controller action.  However replacing the ValueFor with an EditorFor results in the test property being successfully populated on the model that is sent back to the controller action.

Comment: Are you attempt to hide the variable `test`?

Comment: Have you tried examining the output markup? This problem can be easily diagnosed with a basic knowledge of HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's null cause you are only displaying the value. If you want to post back a value that is supposed to be hidden use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.test)`. If you insted want to have a form editor then use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.test)`

Comment: thanks - I'd tried that in a very early attempt and for some reason it didn't work - although it does now.  I guess that's life

Comment: @C.Knight Happy to here that. If that answer was correct then please accept it :)